# Por qué no se reflejan mis cambios en MyEclipse8?

Tags: java, web, glassfish

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto web en MyEclipse8.
Pero cuando hago algún cambio en mis clases, por ejemplo una consulta.
Al momento de subir el proyecto, no se ven reflejados mis cambios.
Estoy utilizando **Glassfish2**.
Ya he quitado el proyecto del servidor, limpie el proyecto y el servidor y nada.
A alguién le ha pasado esto y sabe como resolverlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que colocar tu aplicación en:

```
%GLASSFISH_HOME%/domains/domain1/autodeploy
```

Donde la variable **%GLASSFISH_HOME%** es el directorio de instalación de Glassfish.

Así quedaría:

```
%GLASSFISH_HOME%/domains/domain1/autodeploy/mi-app
```

Referencias:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22712508/how-to-make-a-war-file-auto-deploy
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1757/ghgmi/index.html